# How many close votes do 3k+ users get per day? Is there any way to increase it?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I just reached 3000 rep (yay!) yesterday and I immediately went to the close vote review queue. After working through twenty it said I was out of close votes. Same thing today. Now, I remember reading somewhere (not sure where) that you gain close votes with rep, or review tasks done, or something like that. What I read could've been about flags, I guess, but then I have a question about that too.

So, my question is: what are the flag/close-vote increase points, if that makes sense? At what point do the number of close-votes or flags I have increase? (I do know that you have 10 close votes outside of review queues.)

I'd also like to ask if there are any specific things I should be doing as a 3k user besides going through the review queues (which I have been doing as they became open to me).

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281818/is-using-reputation-to-scale-the-number-of-close-votes-the-best-way

Comment: @DavidZ That's actually interestingly topical. And also a good opportunity to poke some fun at SO's ridiculous close review queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good thing that you're so motivated to go through the review queues!

What increases with successful flagging is the [number of flags you're allowed to cast per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/263383). Unfortunately, after you hit 3k, you won't ever use all those flags because all your off-topic "flags" on questions are now *close votes*.

You get 24 close votes per day, and 20 reviews in the queue per day. This doesn't scale with rep. Every close vote you cast in the queue is deducted from the 24 votes per day you have. You cannot review when you're out of close votes even if you haven't done 20 reviews that day.

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't suppose there's anyway to flag like you close when you are out of close votes? (I only have 2 left for the day, I think. Not sure.) And is there anything else I should be doing as a 3k user?

Comment: @heather No and no. You got close and reopen rights when you hit 3k, but not more, so there's nothign more that would be specific to 3l.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help!